# Styling a DataPager

Tags: css, datapager

I have a listview control attached to a DataPager (or the other way around!) and am wondering if anybody can tell me how you can set the width on the NumericPagerField field?  I have tried setting it via the  NumericButtonCssClass and things like background colors, borders, padding etc. work but anytime I try explicitly stating a width, whatever value I state does not take affect.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Buttons in datapager render in page as `<a><a/>`. "a" element has default value
`display: inline;` and dont accept any width. To apply your width you need to add `display:inline-block;` in your css-style

```
.NumericButtonCssClass
{
    width:25px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```